# Can I get any extra Cookies out of Fool's Buicuit?

Tags: cookie-clicker

There are 5 seasonal updates in Cookie Clicker. They all have upgrades or a way to increase cookie production except Fool's Biscuit. It looks like it's a purely cosmetic change.

[image: Fool's Biscuit]

Am I missing something? Is there a way to get cookies out of Fool's Biscuit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope, Fool's Biscuit, as the name suggests, is essentially worthless.